# Using html5 video tag with XPages

Tags: html, video, xpages, projekktor

Given this example:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

how do you get the "controls" attribute working with XPages?  The DDE editor doesn't seem to like that.  I believe it's expecting it on the format of name="value".

I'm not sure how to do this.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *computedText* for this:

```
<xp:text
   escape="false"
   tagName="video"
   disableTheme="true">
   <xp:this.attrs>
      <xp:attr value="" name="controls" minimized="true" />
      <xp:attr value="320" name="width"/>
      <xp:attr value="240" name="height" />
   </xp:this.attrs>
   <xp:this.value>
      <![CDATA[
         <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" >
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
      ]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

The option *minimized=true* does the trick. The < source > Tags are included as value of the *xp:text*, that's why the XPage ignores the missing ending slashes.

Answer (score 3):

XHTML or XML doesn't allow for name only attributes and XPages is XML. You can do :

```
     <video controls="controls">
         <source="..." />
         ....
      </video>
```

Note the closing slash in source. That should do the trick